# can not find nbconvert.py after git clone and pip install nbconvert

Tags: python, jupyter, nbconvert

I am following the instruction here http://www.slideviper.oquanta.info/tutorial/slideshow_tutorial_slides.html#/10 to convert my ipynb file to a html slideshow.

As I didn't have nbconvert, I `$git clone https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert.git` and `$pip install nbconvert`. Everything looked good.

In my folder `$ls` returns `CONTRIBUTING.md  COPYING.md  docs  MANIFEST.in  nbconvert  README.md  readthedocs.yml  scripts  setup.cfg  setup.py`

Here I could not find python nbconvert.py 
As nbconvert is a folder, I `$cd nbconvert` and `$ls`. It showed:

```
exporters  __init__.py  nbconvertapp.py  preprocessors  templates  utils writers
filters    __main__.py  postprocessors   resources      tests      _version.py
```

Still, I did not see `nbconvert.py` I tried `$python nbconvertapp.py -f reveal myfile.ipynb`, the error:

```
File "nbconvertapp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .exporters.export import get_export_names, get_exporter
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`
```

I am not clear what's going on here. Could someone direct me the right way to insall or use nbconvert so I can translate my ipynb file to a html slideshow? Thank you!

Comment: `pip install nbconvert` and then `jupyter nbconvert <here your commands>`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What should be in `<here your command>`?

Comment: check out the documentation here: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: Thank you. Now I can do it!

Answer (score 0):

You should add c:\python27\Script\jupyter.exe (or wherever this file is) to the windows path, then you should *cd* to where your .ipynb file is and type in a windows cmd console :

jupyter nbconvert youfile.ipynb format

"format" can be : html, slides, pdf, etc...

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Since you are importing a module, the package for nbconvert are installed in your base python path and is accessible anywhere you have access to python. Therefore the correct way to use nbconvert is:

```
jupyter nbconvert <command>
```

If you run just:

```
jupyter nbconvert
```

you will see help information on commands it receives